# ImageView with matrix, on initialization

Tags: android

I have a problem with a scale of one image on imageview. The imageview has scaletype matrix. And I have a custom Touchlistener who let me make zoom and drag&drop, etc.. But when I setimage on imageview, this appears zoomed.

I try solve it, searching many solutions on this web and others. But the last is:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_image);

Matrix mMatrix = iv.getImageMatrix(); mMatrix.setRectToRect(new
  RectF(0, 0, iv.getMeasuredWidth(), iv.getMeasuredHeight()),new
  RectF(0, 0, iv.getMeasuredWidth(), iv.getMeasuredHeight()),
        Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
```

and the xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout...>
.....
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonlayer">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I can't solve it!, the  imageview continues showing wrong!

Thanks in advance!